# Http GET request not happened after OnError in retrofit

Tags: android, http, retrofit, rx-java

I am new to Retrofit and using `com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0`. I am having form filling in android application which can enter address and when clicking on save button
it will make http GET request using flatmap operator in retrofit, and it will give a `error` responses if user enter the wrong pin code  saying that "*invalid pin code*" 
Once after I receive the error response, It will go `OnError()` callback and I am allowing the user to edit the pin code again and clicking on save button again , my `retrofit API` is not making a http request. How to resolve this issue?

```
 ApiClient.createAddress(contact).subscribe(mObserver );

    mObserver = new Subscriber<Contact>() {
    @Override public void onCompleted() {}  

    @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {                        
    onNetworkError(e);
    }

    @Override public void onNext(Contact contact) {             
    saveContact(contact);
    }
    };  

    public static Observable<Contact> createAddress(Contact mAddress) 
    {
    final String name = mAddress.getName();
    final String company = mAddress.getCompany();     
    final String country = mAddress.getCountry(); 

    final Observable<Contact> createAddressObservable = 
    sService.createAddress(name,company,country)
    .flatMap(new Func1<AddressResponse, Observable<? extends Contact>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<? extends Contact> call(
    AddressResponse addressCreateResponse) {

    if (addressCreateResponse.isSuccess()) { 
    return Observable.just(addressCreateResponse.getAddress());
    } 
    else {
    final String errorMessage = addressCreateResponse.getMessage();
    return null; 
    }
    });     
    return createAddressObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

In the above code when I enter wrong pin code it goes to the call back onError , then I allow user to edit the pincode and click on save button , it will call `ApiClient.createAddress(contact, null).subscribe(mObserver)` 
which is not making http get request again. Please help on this.

Comment: Can you please post the code here?

Comment: @SarthakGandhi I have updated the query with code. Please check now